# a function to grep specified files?

Tags: helm, projectile, rgrep

My Emacs customizations reside in a few separate .org files, all in the directory `~/emacs-prelude/personal`. I'm always searching these files to find and change settings.

How can I define a function `search-my-emacs-configutation-files` to search the full text of these files?

It seems like the most obvious way would be to do a `helm-projectile-grep`, but Projectile seems to think the "project" is the entire Emacs-Prelude directory (including all my packages) when in fact I want to search only the subdirectory Personal which has my customizations.

`helm-cmd-t` seemed promising but it seems like it searches only filenames.

`helm-do-grep` works, but it asks me for the directory each time. I'd like to be able to call this function using a single keystroke.

Comment: You can just use `M-x grep`, and customize option `grep-template` to hard-code your directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you need, here is one by using helm's `helm-do-grep-1`.

```el
(defun search-my-emacs-configutation-files ()
  (helm-do-grep-1 '("~/emacs-prelude/personal/*.org")))
```

If you even have `.org` files under some sub-directories under `~/emacs-prelude/personal/`:

```el
(defun search-my-emacs-configutation-files ()
  (helm-do-grep-1 '("~/emacs-prelude/personal") :recurse nil '("*.org")))
```

---

From `C-h f helm-do-grep-1`:

> (helm-do-grep-1 TARGETS &optional RECURSE ZGREP EXTS DEFAULT-INPUT
>   INPUT)

The 1st argument TARGETS is a list of files (including directories).

Answer (score 3):

The package [elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/) is a quite powerful search tool. I just listed the features in [an answer to a similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53281/2370).

Recursive search for occurences of regexp matches in specified files is only one of its simplest applications.

After installation [from melpa](https://www.melpa.org/#/elgrep) you get a comfortable settings dialog window using the menu bar:
`Tools`  → `Search Files (Elgrep)`.

The following settings are sufficient to search the org files in directory `~/KB/Soft/Emacs/elgrepTest/` and its subdirectories for the regexp `\(one\|second\|third\) section`:

Expression: Regexp: `\(one\|second\|third\) section`
Directory: `~/KB/Soft/Emacs/elgrepTest/`
File Name Regular Expression: `\.org\'`
Recurse into subdirectories `[X]`

A picture of the buffer with the search results:

[image: search results in the *elgrep* buffer]

The nice thing that fits perfectly your usecase is that Elgrep lists the calls run over the menu in an `elgrep-call-list` that is part of the `*elgrep-menu*` buffer:

[image: *elgrep-menu* buffer]

You can copy the `Form` entry, paste it into a command and adapt it to your needs.

```el
(defun my-elgrep-call (regexp)
  "Just run Elgrep for my config files."
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Search my config files for: ")))
  (elgrep/i "~/KB/Soft/Emacs/elgrepTest/" "\\.org\\'" regexp :recursive t))
```

Alternatively you can also name the call list entry, e.g. with `Search Config` and reuse it whenever you want. The call list entries are stored on disk when you leave Emacs and recovered at the start of the next session.

When you want to search your config files next time just press the `[Set]` button of the call list entry `Search Config`. The settings of the call list entry are adopted in the menu. Then you can change the regexp and press `[Start Elgrep]`.

Naming the call list entry is important since the first call list entry is overwritten by the next Elgrep call if it is unnamed. This way the user decides which call list entries to keep.

The previous search is quite booring.
Let us try somewhat more interesting.

Assume you have the convention that each Elisp Org source block that contains a function definition should also containe some informative message.
You want to check whether there are some source blocks that contain a function definition but no message call. Thereby, stuff commented out or appearing in strings is irrelevant.

The following Elgrep settings define a search for *records* in Org files that contain matches for the regexp `(defun` and no matches for the regexp `(message`. The `!` before `(message` in the input field negates the match.

The *records* are delimited by matches for regular expression that mark the beginning and the end of Elisp source code blocks.

The *context* is chosen such that the full records are printed in the `*elgrep*` buffer with the search results.

The search function is chosen such that it only accepts matches in Elisp code and not in comments or strings. Therefore, we search with the `emacs-lisp-syntax-table` active.

Expression: List of regexps:
[INS] [DEL] Regexp: `(defun`
[INS] [DEL] Regexp: `!(message`
[INS]
Directory: `~/KB/Soft/Emacs/elgrepTest`
File Name Regular Expression: `\.org\'`
Recurse into subdirectories `[X]`
Beginning of Record: Regexp: `^[[:space:]]*#\+begin_src[[:space:]]+emacs-lisp`
End of Record: Regexp: `^[[:space:]]*#\+end_src\>`
Context Lines Before The Match: Regexp: `` \` ``
Context Lines After The Match: Regexp: `\'`
Search function: `(lambda (&rest args) (with-syntax-table emacs-lisp-mode-syntax-table (apply #'elgrep/re-search-code args)))`

When you click on `[Start Elgrep]` Elgrep executes the search, shows the results, and presents your settings as command in the call list:

```el
(elgrep/i "/mnt/c/Users/Tobias.Zawada/Weiterbildung/Soft/Emacs/elgrepTest" "\\.org\\'"
      ("(defun" "!(message")
      :recursive t :r-beg "^[[:space:]]*#\\+begin_src[[:space:]]+emacs-lisp" :r-end "^[[:space:]]*#\\+end_src\\>" :c-beg "\\`" :c-end "\\'" :search-fun
      (lambda
        (&rest args)
        (with-syntax-table emacs-lisp-mode-syntax-table
          (apply #'elgrep/re-search-code args))))
```

You can copy that entry and use it in your self-made Elisp command.
But, there is actually little need to define your own command since you can re-use the call list entry in the elgrep menu.